# PHP exec() not working as expected

Tags: php

I'm writing an application that will allow approved developers to submit php code to our database to be run at a later time.

I'm attempting to implement a system where before their code is run it is checked for any issues.

I found the following code at http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/4819-before-eval-how-can-one-test-string-see-if-valid-php-code

```
function checkPHP($string) {
    $string = escapeshellcmd($string);
    exec("php -r \"$string\"",$output,$exit);
    if($exit==0) return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
}

/* tests */
$test = array ("print ('foo');",
               "print (\"foo\");",
               "pint ('foo');",
               "print ('foo);",
               "print ('foo','bar');"
);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($test);$i++) {
    print $test[$i];
    if(checkPHP($test[$i])) {
      print " is ok.<br />\n";
    } else {
      print " not ok.<br />\n";
    }
}
```

When I use it I get:

**print ('foo'); is ok.

print ("foo"); is ok.

pint ('foo'); is ok.

print ('foo); is ok.

print ('foo','bar'); is ok.**

I'm running Apache 2.2 / PHP 5.3.8 Safe Mode off

Comment: Installed modules that may be relavant include mod_suexec and mod_cgi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php` command expects to execute code from either `STDIN` or a file. The -r flag will evaluate what follows without the need for the `<?php ?>` tags, however it's still waiting for a filename after that.

One solution is to write the code you want evaluated and pass its name to `php`. That'd change your `eval` command to `eval ("php $string", $output, $exit);` where $string is the filename where the code to be executed (tested) resides.

You will need to make sure that the file begins with `<?php` so as not to get an error.

This works

```
function checkPHP($string) {
   $string = escapeshellcmd($string);
   exec("php -l $string",$output,$exit);
   return ($exit == 0 ? TRUE : FALSE);
}

/* tests */
$test = array ("print ('foo');",
               "print (\"foo\");",
               "pint ('foo');",
               "print ('foo);",
               "print ('foo','bar');"
);

foreach ($test as $code){
   $fd = fopen('code.dat', 'w');
   fwrite($fd, "<?php \n" . $code . "\n ?>\n");
   fclose($fd);

   print $code;
   if(checkPHP("code.dat")) {
      print " is ok.<br />\n";
   } else {
      print " not ok.<br />\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using **php -l -r**. The **-l** flag performs a syntax check. I don't know if the **-r** flag is necessary if you use -l.

update: I tried this in the command line. Here's what I got when using correct syntax:

```
$ php -l            # what I executed
<?php                   #
print ('foo');          #  What I entered
?>                      #
No syntax errors detected in -   # What I got

$ echo $?  
0             # exit status
```

And the next using incorrect syntax:

```
$ php -l
<?php
print ('foo);
?>

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in - on line 2
No syntax errors detected in -

$ echo $?
0
```

And one last try:

```
$ php -l
<?php
kla asd a sss;    # after entering this line, the command aborted itself with the
                  # next message

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in - on line 2
Errors parsing -

$ echo $?
255
```

First and last case result in what we should expect, but the middle case is not. I would expect a != 0 exit status on this, but it seems that everything is ok (which clearly is not). So maybe your only option (that I can think of, at least) is, if you get 0 exit stats, parse the output and count the number of lines, look for *warning* or some other specific words?

Also, take note that **-l** only checks for syntax error, and cannot find errors at runtime. This means that calling an undefined function will be undetected by **php -l**.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. With **php -l -r** I get the same, but with **php -l** I get **not ok** on all lines.

Comment: **-r** makes unnecessary to put the opening and closing tags. Maybe you can try adding them yourself `$string = "<?php " . escapeshellcmd($string) . " ?>";` and do just **php -l** ?

Comment: Thanks Carlos - still no joy - getting **not ok** as before. Curious as to what was being returned I added `print $exit` to the else statement and I'm getting **255**

Comment: Thank you Carlos. Not quite what I'm after. Your time is much appreciated.